# python3 importing pygame results in PyCObject_AsVoidPtr

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, runtime-error

I have encountered difficulty putting pygame together with python3 on my MacBookPro.

I installed Python 3.3, and my MacOS is running version 10.7.5.

Then I downloaded pygamev1.9.1 source code, and followed instructions in http://programming.itcarlow.ie/PyGameInstall.pdf

Compilation and installation was smooth until I issued "import pygame" inside python3.

Then I encountered the following "PyCobJect_AsVoidPtr" error (further text following error message):

> > > import pygame
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/**init**.py", line 95, in 
> > >           from pygame.base import *
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_AsVoidPtr
> > >         Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/base.so
> > >         Expected in: flat namespace
> > >        in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/base.so

A search on google indicates this symbol has been removed since Python3.2:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2011-March/108882.html

Can someone please give me some advice on how to get pygame working on Python3.3?

More so, whereas I am aware the pygame/python3 developers are busy with their work, but I would certainly appreciate it if someone can provide precompiled pygame binaries for python3. I have limited computer skills, and I just want to go ahead and learn Python3 and pygame, and this is seriously stunting my interest.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you were trying to compile from source, but builds on Python 3.3, to my knowledge, are not yet supported (as of January 2013).  In fact, the only binaries I'm aware of for PyGame and Python 3.3 are [unofficial builds and Windows only](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

You should consider instead using a previous version of Python (e.g. Python 2.7.*), PyGame builds/binaries on which are well-supported.  Any points on setting up should be directed to the [pygame-users mailing list](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/info#Mailing%20List), if they weren't already.

Comment: Hello Ian, thanks for answering my question. This is technically beyond me. I have given up trying to use Pygame with Python3.3 on Mac. I am resorting to installing Pygame with Python3.3 on Windows. That is a breeze thus far. Thanks again.

Comment: Mmmkay. I'm just saying that what you wanted to do--use PyGame on Mac--is not as problematic if you had just been using Python 2.*.